# Retrieve many values associated with the given key at once using Scala

Tags: scala, scala-collections

I have a map with hundreds of elements and I want to retrieve many value at once associated with the given key.

Example:

```
Map(t1 -> 1),(t2 -> 2),.....(t340 ->340)
```

I know I can use the apply method but i'm trying to retrieve like 50 values at once and this would make the code to look like:

```
val a = map.apply("t1","t2","t3","t4","t5","t6"...."t50)
```

Are there any other ways that i can retrieve many values at once using apply method or other methods of the scala map collection?

Comment: If you retrieve more than one value at once (where each attempt might fail) wouldn't the result be also... collection?

Comment: Do you have a collection of keys? or just varargs? What happens with the keys that are not present in the map? I see three alternatives: 1. A **List** of **Options**, one for each key. - 2. An **Option** of a **List**, if at least one element is missing the whole operation is aborted. - 3. A list of values that only includes the found ones. - Which of these three alternatives do you want?

Comment: What about `filter`ing the map the values you desire?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what kind of output you expect it can be done in many different ways.

If you are expecting collection, you could do something like:

```
val keys: List[String]
keys.flatMap(map.get) // List[Int]
```

where you would get a list of values ordered according to keys, but if there were no value for a key it would be skipped.

If you needed values in a collection and order would be irrelevant then

```
val keySet = keys.toSet
map.filter(p => keySet(p._1)).values
```

should be enough.

Yet another option would be:

```
keys.map { k =>
  k -> map.get(k)
}
```

to avoid loosing information which values were present and which not. Though this wouldn't be much different in practice than just:

```
map.filter(p => keySet(p._1))
```

If you expected fixed number of keys, and all have to be present, then I can only see this as:

```
for {
  a1 <- map.get(k1)
  a2 <- map.get(k2)
  ...
  an <- map.get(kn)
} yield (a1, a2, ..., an)
```

which would return Option of tuple. That could be written in a prettier way using Cats e.g.

```
(map.get(k1), map.get(k2), ..., map.get(kn)).tupled
```

though most extension methods (and tuples) support up to 22 arguments, so I can only see solving your problem for 50 keys with a collection. (Or very long for comprehension yielding custom 50-field case class).